# Why do some developers make their base contract inherit its Interface?

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, interfaces, inheritance, natspec

Some protocols and developers inherit the contract's [Interface](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.20/contracts.html#interfaces) inside of the base contract and then have the interface contain the actual [NatSpec](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.20/style-guide.html#natspec), is this simply for human readability/code organization? It definitely helps establish a clear relationship between the contract and its interface, but are there any other reasons besides this?

**Aave:**

[Contract](https://github.com/aave/aave-v3-core/blob/master/contracts/protocol/pool/Pool.sol)

```js
contract Pool is VersionedInitializable, PoolStorage, IPool {
```

```js
/// @inheritdoc IPool
  function backUnbacked(
    address asset,
    uint256 amount,
    uint256 fee
  ) external virtual override onlyBridge returns (uint256) {
    return
      BridgeLogic.executeBackUnbacked(_reserves[asset], asset, amount, fee, _bridgeProtocolFee);
  }
```

[Interface](https://github.com/aave/aave-v3-core/blob/master/contracts/interfaces/IPool.sol)

```js
/**
   * @notice Back the current unbacked underlying with `amount` and pay `fee`.
   * @param asset The address of the underlying asset to back
   * @param amount The amount to back
   * @param fee The amount paid in fees
   * @return The backed amount
   */
  function backUnbacked(address asset, uint256 amount, uint256 fee) external returns (uint256);
```

**Sablier:**

[Contract](https://github.com/sablier-labs/v2-core/blob/main/src/SablierV2LockupLinear.sol)

```js
contract SablierV2LockupLinear is
    ISablierV2LockupLinear, // 5 inherited components
    SablierV2Lockup // 14 inherited components
{
```

```js
  /// @inheritdoc ISablierV2Lockup
    function getEndTime(uint256 streamId) external view override notNull(streamId) returns (uint40 endTime) {
        endTime = _streams[streamId].endTime;
    }
```

[Interface](https://github.com/sablier-labs/v2-core/blob/main/src/interfaces/ISablierV2Lockup.sol)

```js
/// @notice Retrieves the stream's end time, which is a Unix timestamp.
    /// @dev Reverts if `streamId` references a null stream.
    /// @param streamId The stream id for the query.
    function getEndTime(uint256 streamId) external view returns (uint40 endTime);
```

Comment: See related discussion [here](https://twitter.com/PaulRBerg/status/1536002060818305024).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is simply for human readability/code organization.

Most projects use other smart contracts to write their own.

For instance, if you want to create your ERC20 tokens, you might use OpenZeppelin libraries. Then, you can inherit your smart contract from IERC2O contract. In that way, you make sure you will not forget an ERC20 standard function.